# How do I use reportviewer in Visual Studio 2015 community?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer

Can someone please help with using reportviewer in Visual Studia 2015 Community?  I have made sure that SQL Server Data Tools are installed.  I have added reportviewer in the add items of the Visual Studio toolbox, reset the the toolbox.  In the toolbox I see a reporting tab which has reportviewer but it is greyed out so I can't use it.  I can't figure out how t get the reportviewer available?  I am at a loss.

Comment: Can you be more specific in what kind of application you are trying to use the report viewer in?  Is it a WinForms, WPF, WebForms, MVC, Lightswitch?

Comment: #Erik Funkenbusch - I am creating a WPF. I need to produce a report that I can print. I originally had a datagrid with the info I needed but cannot figure out how to print the data from a datagrid. I did some searching and found info on the reportviewer and thought that might be a good way to create a formatted report and print it. But I can't even add the reportviewer control

Comment: Microsoft has a web page on this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx  - I don't have time to summarize this as an answer, so someone else is welcome to and get the rep for it.